# Determine equivalent constant voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis

As the current drawn from a dc power supply is increased from 600mA to 800mA,the terminal voltage decreases from 24 to 23V.determine the equivalent constant -voltage source.
The answer is 27v and 5 ohms but i get 1v(24-23)how do we do it?

Comment: Can you draw the circuit to see what is going on? In your case, you have a Voltage source with internal resistance, and the load is connected. The load current consumption is from 600mA to 800mA, the voltage across the load decreases from 24V to 23V. And your job is to find the internal resistance value and the source voltage.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to model the power supply as a constant voltage source, in series with a resistor. Completing the circuit with a load gives the diagram below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSMmLx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You know two situations for this circuit. In one, the load voltage is 24V, and the current is 600 mA. In the other case, the load voltage is 23V, and the current is 800 mA.

For both these cases, the voltage around the loop needs to add up to zero. This means that the voltage V1 needs to be equal to the sum of the load voltage, and the voltage drop across the resistor. The voltage drop across the resistor depends on the current as $$V_R = I \times R_1$$

We can now set up two equations for the system
$$V_1 = 24V + 600mA \times R_1$$
$$V_1 = 23V + 800mA \times R_1$$
and solving this system of equations* does indeed give us the correct solution of R1 = 5Ω and V1 = 27V.